# How to display language switcher as dropdown in Polylang?

Tags: wordpress, language-switching, polylang

I don't have display as dropdown in Appereance -> Menu -> Language switcher. How can i solve it?

Here is an image

[image: Here is an image]

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Your question hasn´t become any better since posting on WP:SE: [Language switcher, don't have dispaly as dropdown. Polylang on hold](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271784/language-switcher-dont-have-dispaly-as-dropdown-polylang) Please improve your question and take note, that this is no plugin support board.

Comment: take a look here https://polylang.pro/doc/widgets/

Comment: And  here: https://polylang.pro/doc-category/the-language-switcher/

Comment: And here, if you can code, take a look to pll_the_languages() function: https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/

Comment: ...And please, do not mind cops. Yes, sadly enough they are everywhere, but there are also people who want to help when common sense can go behind the Sacred Rules.

Comment: you really want to run this with the following categories - home, about us, product , news, contact - language switcher

Answer (score 8):

You should alternatively use the PHP function to display it, try this

```
<?php pll_the_languages( array( 'dropdown' => 1 ) ); ?>
```

The documentation is here - https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/#pll_the_languages

Comment: Although this is the right answer, I always prefer to give a string name to the `dropdown` argument (`desktop`, `mobile`). The point is that if you use it twice on your page (e.g. mobile and desktop menu) the generated code won't work with `1` as the value (because of non unique DOM id).

Answer (score 2):

In appearance->menus, go in screen options on top right of you screen and check the “Language switcher” checkbox. You then should have a new metabox which allows to add a language switcher just as you add another menu item.

Answer (score 0):

@NJENGAH's answer is correct.

Additionally, if you would like to have 2 drop-downs on the same page, i.e. header and footer, increment the `dropdown` array value for the subsequent calls by `1`.

````
<?php pll_the_languages( ['dropdown' => 2 ] ); ?>```

and so on...
````